# Applescript failing to build on false syntax error

Tags: bash, macos, syntax, applescript

Okay, I've poured over this issue a good 20 times now, and it has me baffled. I was writing an unofficial updater for the "canary" build of Citra Emu. At first everything went off without a hitch, the app was working perfectly, however it had a heavy reliance on Bash scripts with hard-coded paths. I wanted to make them more dynamic to allow easier installation and maintenance across multiple machines/macOS versions.

I decided the best option was to convert the remainder of the code to Applescript, and only make Bash calls via `do shell script` when necessary. Now for the most part this worked. The program builds fine, but it seems to fail due to a lone syntax error, and an invisible one at that. Here's the code (please pardon the messiness.):

```
tell application "Citra" to display dialog "Update Citra to the newest build?" buttons {"Update", "Open Current Build"} default button "Update" with title "Citra Canary Updater" with icon path to resource "Citra.icns" in bundle (path to application "Citra")

if the button returned of the result is "Update" then
  tell application "System Events" to write "DoUpdate" to file (path to resource "update/ShoudUpdate" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  else
  tell application "System Events" to write "NotUpdate" to file (path to resource "update/ShouldUpdate" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
end if

set ShouldUpdate to read file (path to resource "update/ShouldUpdate" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))

if ShouldUpdate is equal to "DoUpdate" then
  tell application "System Events" to write "true" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateIsRunning" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "System Events" to write "0" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "System Events" to write "Downloading Build Archive" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateAction" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "System Events" to write "Pinging update server..." to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "Citra Canary Updater"
      activate
  end tell
  else
  tell application "System Events"
      do shell script ("~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/canary/citra-qt.app/Contents/MacOS/citra-qt-bin")
  end tell
end if
set UpdateServerIP to "github.com"  
try
   set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 1" & UpdateServerIP)
   tell application "System Events" to write "yes" to file (path to resource "update/ServerIsAvailable" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
on error
   tell application "System Events" to write "no" to file (path to resource "update/ServerIsAvailable" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
end try
set ServerIsAvailable to read file (path to resource "update/ServerIsAvailable" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))

if ServerIsAvailable is equal to "yes" then
  tell application "System Events" to write "10" to file (path to  resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))  
  tell application "System Events" to write "Retrieving files..." to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "System Events"
   do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/wget -O citra-osx.tgz $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/citra-emu/citra-canary/releases/latest | grep 'browser_' | cut -d\" -f4 | grep osx | grep tar.gz)")
  end tell
  else
  tell application "System Events" to write "false" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateIsRunning" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "System Events" to write "0" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "System Events" to write "NULL" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateAction" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "System Events" to write "NULL" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  tell application "Citra" to display dialog "The update server is not available. Please try again later." buttons {"Open Current Build", "Close"} default button "Open Current Build" with title "Citra Canary Updater" with icon caution
  if the button returned of the result is "Open Current Build" then
    tell application "System Events"
        do shell script ("~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/canary/citra-qt.app/Contents/MacOS/citra-qt-bin")
    end tell
  end if
end if

tell application "System Events"
    if exists file ((path to home folder from user domain as text) & "citra-osx.tgz") then
      tell application "System Events" to write "35" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "Installing New Build" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateAction" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "Moving files to temp directory..." to file (path to resource "updates/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events"
          do shell script ("mv ~/citra-osx.tgz ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/citra-osx.tgz")
      end tell
      tell application "System Events" to write "40" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "Wiping old build..." to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events"
          do shell script ("cd ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/; rm -R canary/;")
      end tell
      tell application "System Events" to write "55" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "Extracting build archive..." to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events"
          do shell script ("cd ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/; tar xzvf citra-osx.tgz;")
      end tell
      tell application "System Events" to write "65" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "Deleting build archive..." to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events"
          do shell script ("cd ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/; rm citra-osz.tgz;")
      end tell
      tell application "System Events" to write "80" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "Moving files to permanent directory..." to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events"
          do shell script ("cd ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/; mv citra-osx* canary/;")
      end tell
      tell application "System Events" to write "100" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "Done" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateAction" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
  delay 3
      tell application "System Events" to write "false" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateIsRunning" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "0" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "NULL" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateAction" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "NULL" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events"
          do shell script ("~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/canary/citra-qt.app/Contents/MacOS/citra-qt-bin & disown")
      end tell
      else
      tell application "System Events" to write "false" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateIsRunning" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "0" to file (path to resource "update/UpdatePercentage" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "NULL" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateAction" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "System Events" to write "NULL" to file (path to resource "update/UpdateStatus" in bundle (path to application "Citra"))
      tell application "Citra" to display dialog "Your system is not supported by the latest build. Please try again later." buttons {"Open Current Build", "Close"} default button "Open Current Build" with title "Citra Canary Updater" with icon caution
      if the button returned of the result is "Open Current Build" then
        tell application "System Events"
             do shell script ("~/Library/Application\\ Support/Citra/canary/citra-qt.app/Contents/MacOS/citra-qt-bin")
        end tell
      end if
    end if
end tell
```

Now I realize this is a rather redundant and sloppy way of handling the progress bar, but please hold your judgement, as the issue at hand is far more intriguing. When trying to run this script directly it returns:

> The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “1533:1534: syntax error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)”

I'll be frank, I haven't the slightest clue what the *1533:1534:* part is about, I've never been able to tell what this part of an Applescript error code represents, given that it's structured like a C debugger pointing to the line and column at which the error occurred, but there obviously are most certainly not 1500 lines in this script.

It seems to be a standard syntax error, however I've read over this entire script as I said, a good 20 times and I just *cannot* find what is causing this syntax error. It builds fine in Script Editor, but attempting to run it causes the above error, same with saving and running as an Application Bundle or Bash script.

What's more is that neither the Bash syntax highlighting in Xcode or the Applescript syntax highlighting in Script Editor are helping bring any typos to my attention. In fact, according to their syntax highlighting everything is fine.

Please if anyone can help me figure out what part of this script is broken, it will be greatly appreciated. I'm driving myself up a wall trying to fix this at this point.

Comment: If you want help debugging code, the question really should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to post a minimally amount of code that we can reproduce the issue, not the entire script. Especially because it's dealing with a third party app that we may not have installed. Also, I'd suggest avoiding the use of `~` in the `do shell script` _command_ and use `$HOME` in its place. Also do not escape spaces with a backslash if you also double-quote the path filename. Which `do shell script` _command_ is it failing on?

Comment: To rule out which `do shell script` _command_ you're having an issue with, you should one at a time validate the command in Terminal then take the working Terminal command and try it in a `do shell script` _command_, escaping and or single/double quoting as may be necessary. Make sure each one works in both Terminal and then AppleScript's `do shell script` _command_. Debugging can be a painful process, however if you're methodical about it and break in down into smaller pieces it's less painful and easier to resolve the issue.

Comment: The easiest one to fix is `set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 1" & UpdateServerIP)`, put a _space_ after the `1` in `"ping -c 1"` so its: `set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 1 " & UpdateServerIP)`

Comment: There are things I see wrong with your code, e.g. your wrapping the built-in AppleScript `do shell script` command in a `tell application "System Events"` statement block, that's wrong, it's run in the context of a `tell current application` statement block. Also I see issues with `do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/wget -O citra-osx.tgz $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/citra-emu/citra-canary/releases/latest | grep 'browser_' | cut -d\" -f4 | grep osx | grep tar.gz)")`, by itself is doesn't compile. You don't need to individually use `tell application "System Events"  like you are either.